# Regex for Matching Words within a String

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Here is what I  have so far, but it only matches the beginning of the target string:

```
var enteredText = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");

$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function(array, term) {
    var enteredText = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");

    return $.grep(array, function(value) {
        return enteredText.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};
```

Note: $.ui.autocomplete.filter  allows me to change  how jQuery UI searches the terms with autocomplete.

"term" is the text entered into the input box.

"$.grep" plugs each element in the autocomplete "array" into "function(value)"

**EDIT 1:**
I'm looking for a Regex to search from the beginning of each word in a string. For example, "an" matches "I like Andy" but not "I like candy".

Comment: so how do you want to search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is what I have so far, but it only matches the beginning of the target string:

to address that problem

try this:

Remove `^` since you don't want only at the beginning of the string.

```
var enteredText = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
```

And for this:

> EDIT 1: I'm looking for a Regex to search from the beginning of each
>   word in a string. For example, "an" matches "I like Andy" but not "I
>   like candy".

Since you say, you want to match, you have to prefix and suffix your regex with `.+?`. Like

```
var enteredText = new RegExp(".*"+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term)+".*", "i");
```

Comment: Without "^", the search is similar to "contains" which is really slow for a huge list. See my EDIT

Comment: but you said you wanted to search not only at the beginning right?

Comment: Basically, the strings in the array contain multiple words separated by spaces. The user enters one word or partially that one word. It should then match the strings that contains a word matching the beginning of that partial word.